# write a program that reads a text file with two columns of numbers then calculates the total and average of each column?

Tags: python

I have to write a program that reads a text file with two columns of numbers then calculates the total and average of each column. I was able to separate the columns, but i keep getting a variety of errors when i try to find the sum, like "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'". Here is what i have so far:

```
def main():
    print("This program will read the file and calculate the total and average of each column of  numbers")
    filename= input("\nWhat is the name of the file?")
    myfile = open(filename, "r")
    with open("numbers.txt") as myfile:
        for line in myfile:
            parts = line.split()
            if len(parts) > 1:
                total = sum(parts[0])
                total2 = sum(parts[1])
                print(total)
                print(total2)

main()
```

Comment: that error means you can't add a string (like "1") to a number (like 1). Use int("1") to convert the string "1" to the number 1.

Comment: When you read the numbers from your file they are in a `string` format. Change the sum calculation to this `int(sum(parts[0])`

Comment: it returns with the same error

Comment: @Beginner, it's correct that he must use `int` to convert from string to integer, but your code is inverted. It should be `sum(int(parts[0]))`.

Comment: @leogama - Nice catch!! Such a stupid mistake

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the strings with the `float` function. You also aren't actually incrementing your `total` and `total2`, but instead assigning them at each value.

This should do what you want:

```
def main():
    print("This program will read the file and calculate the total and average of each column of  numbers")
    filename= input("\nWhat is the name of the file?")
    myfile = open(filename, "r")
    with open("numbers.txt") as myfile:
        count = 0
        total = 0.0
        total2 = 0.0
        for line in myfile:
            parts = line.split()
            if len(parts) > 1:
                total += float(parts[0])
                total2 += float(parts[1])
                count += 1
        print(total)
        print(total2)
        print(total / count)
        print(total2 / count)
```

Comment: Actually, the `split` call does take care of the trailing newline:

S.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1) -> list of strings

Return a list of the words in S, using sep as the delimiter string.  If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit splits are done. **If sep is not specified or is None**, any whitespace string is a separator and empty strings are removed from the result.

Comment: @leogama Ah, yes, in this case `split` will do the right thing, but it is a common problem, if you were just reading a single integer from the file.

Comment: thanks for all the help im still getting the error, ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '12.3'

Comment: Then your numbers aren't integers and you should use `float` instead. I've updated my answer.